# Bootstrap treeview expand collapse icon coming for leaf nodes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-treeview

I am using [bootstrap treeview](http://jonmiles.github.io/bootstrap-treeview/). For some reason, even the leaf nodes are having expand/collapse icons. I want to show expand/collapse icons only for non-leaf nodes?

I am using following config:

```
  $('#tree').treeview({data: scope.tree, showCheckbox: true});
  $('#tree').treeview('collapseAll', { silent: true });
```

I am sure there must be a configuration to enable disable expand/collapse icons for leaf nodes in treeview.

Answer (score 5):

To answer my own question, In the JSON, the nodes property **needs to be set as** `null` for leaf nodes. **I was sending it as** `empty array []`

```
var tree = [
  {
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Grandchild 1"
          },
          {
            text: "Grandchild 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    text: "Parent 4"
    nodes: []  // =======> set this as null
  }
];
```